# Azure Storage, using BlobRequestOptions without CloudBlobClient

Tags: c#, azure, security, azure-storage

The app I'm building downloads and uploads some blockblobs on azure. I'm currently using the v6.1 and everything works fine. But i cannot upgrade to v7 because of the following issue :

I'm maybe totally wrong, but I decided not to have a CloudBlobClient in my application because I don't want it to store the connection string. 
Instead, the container from which I will upload / download is initiated through a SAS URI provided by a web service so my actual (and shortened) download workflow is the following :

```
//jsonstring contains a SAS URI provided by a web service
var jsonString = await Response.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
CloudBlobContainer cloudContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(jsonString.Replace('"', ' ').Trim()));

ICloudBlob blob = cloudContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(item.blobName);
await blob.FetchAttributesAsync();
blob.ServiceClient.ParallelOperationThreadCount = 10;

asyncresult = m_Blob.BeginDownloadToStream(pstream, blobTransferCompletedCallback, new BlobTransferAsyncState(m_Blob, pstream));
```

This works very well, but blob.ServiceClient.ParallelOperationThreadCount = 10; is deprecated and from what I've seen yet the supersceding item BlobRequestOptions can only be defined on a CloudBlobClient which I decided (maybe for bad reasons) not to use.

I was considering my various options and was looking for some advices on which one should be the best :
1- A miracle happens and I can use BlobRequestOptions without CloudBlobClient 
2- I stay on Azure Storage API v6.1
3- I get a CLoudBLobClient from my MVC web service and I use it
4- Having a connection string in the app is not a security leak so I can use a CloudBlobClient as everyone does on the net

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every method call which can trigger request in Azure Storage Client Library has an overload accepting RequestOption. For example, CloudBlob.BeginDownloadToStream has the overload: [CloudBlob.BeginDownloadToStream Method (Stream, AccessCondition, **BlobRequestOptions**, OperationContext, AsyncCallback, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt423217.aspx).

Comment: Looked in every azure method I implemented except the BeginUploadFromStream. Thanks !

Comment: Additionally, all of the defaults on the ServiceClient were deprecated in favor of the ServiceClient's default requestOptions object.  If you don't want to pass in a RequestOptions object with each request, you should still be able to set a default with blob.ServiceClient.DefaultRequestOptions.ParallelOperationThreadCount